# How to capture a WebElement value using QTP and put that value in the body of an e-mail in the middle of a sentence

Tags: email, qtp

I found a similar question that asks how to get a value of a WebElement and put it in an excel file and then e-mail the excel file, but how do I put that value of a WEbElement in the body of an e-mail in the middle of a sentence and NOT in an excel file?

For example, I want to capture a WebElement that tells me how many coke points I have and then I want to e-mail myself that value.  Something like: "You have 500 Coke Points now".

This is what I have, but i'm getting a syntax error:

```
Dim ResultsFile
Set objOutlook=CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg=objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
objOutlookMsg.To="email@email.com"
ResultsFile="C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\CkeZeroPoints.xlsx"
objOutlookMsg.Subject="Coke Zero points"
objOutlookMsg.Body="You now have" &Browser("Sweepstakes.*").Page("Sweepstakes.*").WebElement("htmlID:=glPointsText").GetRoProperty("innertext") "Coke Zero points."
objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add(ResultsFile)
objOutlookMsg.Display
objOutlookMsg.Send
Set objOutlookMsg=Nothing
Set objOutlook=Nothing
```

The syntax error starts on line 7.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an ampersand (`&`):

```
Dim ResultsFile, innerText
Set objOutlook=CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg=objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

' Better to separate tasks so you can trap errors earlier
innerText = Browser("Sweepstakes.*").Page("Sweepstakes.*").WebElement("htmlID:=glPointsText").GetRoProperty("innertext")
ResultsFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\CkeZeroPoints.xlsx"

' email handling here, you can refactor this in a separate method
objOutlookMsg.To  ="email@email.com"
objOutlookMsg.Subject = "Coke Zero points"
objOutlookMsg.Body = "You now have " & innerText & " Coke Zero points."  ' <-- ampersand added on this line.
objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add ResultsFile  ' <-- parenthesis removed, only us parenthesis if
                                           ' you are calling a (returning) function
objOutlookMsg.Display
objOutlookMsg.Send
Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```